# Accepting comments as answers

Tags: discussion, comment, answers, accepted-answer

Sometimes a comment will suffice to answer a person's question. This may be because they are only missing one small step in the argument, or because they can be pointed to a resource that answers their question fully.

In such cases, it could be a good idea to be able to *accept* a *comment* as the *answer* to the question, in the same way that answers can already be accepted. (It may not be appropriate to award 15 reputation points in this case, however).

The advantage here would be that questions answered by comments could then be removed from the 'unanswered questions' section, making it easier for other users to identify which questions still need to be resolved.

What are your thoughts on this?

Cheers
Frank.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been discussed before and was rejected by the SE team. If you see a comment answer, you can always leave an answer yourself (make it CW so you don't look like you're gaming for rep) with credit to the user who left the comment. There is a chat room (the crusade of answers) where you can solicit an upvote to remove the question from the queue.

Comment: OK, thanks. What were the reasons for the rejection? Can the discussion still be found?

Comment: [What should one do when one's question has been answered in the comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments)

Answer (score 17):

This has been discussed previously [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149699/a-method-for-the-op-to-accept-comments) at meta.SO. The consensus was that the feature would not be useful, and would undermine the answer/comment divide.

Answer (score 5):

As stated above, for good or ill accepting comments isn't something we're going to be able to do. However, note that when a question *is* answered in the comments (despite the fact that that's not what comments are for) and nobody "steps up" to the plate, this presents a great opportunity for the OP: rephrase the comments in an answer of their own.

Commenting on Alex Becker's comment (appropriately), this is the *one* case in which I think turning comments into an answer does not necessarily warrant CW-ifying: if the OP can synthesize the new information they've been given well enough to write it up in their own words, they *have* earned some Shiny Internet Pointz. *(IMO a high-rep user should still CW-ify such an answer, though.)*

> That said, obviously such an answer still **does** need to $(i)$ give credit to the original comments it's drawing on and $(ii)$ not just copy-paste those comments.

Answer (score -6):

I really think we need to accept comments as answers.

Perhaps, once a comment is accepted as an answer, it can get automatically duplicated as an answer, and a link to it is shown from the comment?